# How does Linaro schedule OPTEE?

Tags: arm, scheduler, trustzone, op-tee

I want to know which part of the code is the scheduler of project OPTEEhttps://github.com/OP-TEE.

More specifically, the code decides that on which CPU secure world and normal word processes are running for multicore architecture.

Any advice is genuinely appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it even has a scheduler? The [design](https://github.com/OP-TEE/optee_os/blob/master/documentation/optee_design.md) and [interrupt handling](https://github.com/OP-TEE/optee_os/blob/master/documentation/interrupt_handling.md) docs rather imply that any event is simply dispatched to the relevant trusted application on whichever core it occurs.

Comment: ...[apparently not](https://github.com/OP-TEE/optee_os/issues/332).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and link @Notlikethat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm one of the Linaro developers working directly with OP-TEE and OP-TEE as such has no scheduler, instead it's being entirely scheduled by Linux kernel. It's not tied to a single core either, after being in Linux kernel and you're about to re-enter secure world it could be any of the cores where you continue running your ongoing job. So in short, there is no scheduler in OP-TEE.

Comment: Yes, nice explanation