# Is it possible to create a secure world OS without a normal world OS in ARM TrustZone?

Tags: arm, qemu, trustzone, op-tee

I currently working with OPTEE on QEMU to create a trusted application in ARM trustzone.
I wonder can OPTEE work without a normal world OS (like linux).

I have tried to modify ARM trusted firmware to skip the boot process which loading normal world component. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: You may be more likely to get an answer if you ask this question somewhere where OPTEE users and developers hang out, like their mailing list.

Comment: op-tee is a 'library' which is called from normal world to perform tasks.  For example it may encrypt/decrypt a binary blob with a key.  Trust Zone supports more and can host an OS in the secure world.  The issue is that OP-TEE will want to call things through an SMC interface, which needs a monitor mode setup.  You would need to change this interface to SWI/SVC or something.  I think you need to state what exactly your goals are.  Ie, you made a ['trusted application'](https://optee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/building/trusted_applications.html); that is normal world?  Not clear what you want.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481671/how-does-linaro-schedule-optee) and I update [op-tee wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/op-tee/info) with some info.

Comment: @artlessnoise I'm sorry for my unclear statement. My goal is to create a secure application without to startup a rich normal world OS, since I want to keep my application to be as light as possible. Did you mean I need to create another interface to substitute normal world OS to let my application call secure world service? Many thanks for your response.